# How can i update plist file which has many group item in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, plist

[image: screenshot]

I have a plist file like this, and now i want to edit the row.

For example, i want to edit row "ZFILMSEAT" in Item 1.

Please somebody suggest me how to update data in plist file.

Comment: Check this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867337/how-can-i-save-retrieve-delete-update-my-data-in-plist-file-in-ios) out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, When you retrieve the `.plist` file, store it as `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your plist name" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSMutableArray *filmsPlaying = [[NSMutableArray alloc] iniWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"FilmsPlaying"]];
NSMutableDictionary *filmToEdit = [filmsPlaying objectAtIndex:1];// IRL run a loop to get your desired film
NSString *newSeats = @"1-2-9";
[filmToEdit setObject:newSeats forKey:@"ZFILMSEAT"];
[filmsPlaying replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:filmsToEdit];
[dict setObject:filmsPlaying forKey:@"FilmsPlaying"];
```

Here you have the film you want to edit. After you have made your edition to that dictionary, you need to write it back to App's document dir. (**NOTE:** You CANNOT save it back to your main bundle but you can write it to Documents instead).

```
NSString *pathForPlist = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
pathForPlist = [savingPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"your plist name.plist"];
[dict writeToFile:savingPath automically:YES];
```

To edit it in the main bundle without any programming, you can simply open it in any text editor or xcode itself and make your edition. Nothing techie about that.