# How to save NSString under Key in info plist?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsstring, save, info.plist

i want to save NSString under Background image key in info plist . how can i do that . any help ?

i don't know how to read/write data in info.plist. can anybody tell me how to do that ?

Comment: This link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867337/how-can-i-save-retrieve-delete-update-my-data-in-plist-file-in-ios

Comment: Thanks sir... helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update or insert data .
NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Mysoot.plist"]; //3

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //4
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Myspot" ofType:@"plist"]; //5

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //6
}
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

[data removeObjectForKey:@"BackgroundImage"];
    [data setObject:imageName forKey:@"BackgroundImage"];

```
[data writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

Right click your app's **info.plist > open as > source code**