# I want to save the objects with NSUserDefault, some of them would sometimes be deleted after finishing the app in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I am making the view page to show the information of the list of downloaded songs. But I faced some unexpected situation.

```
func setDownloadedContentInformation(fileID:String){
    var downloadedContentInformation = Dictionary<String, NSData>()
    var deliveringInfo : PodUnit? = PodUnit() 
    deliveringInfo = self.info;
    deliveringInfo?.downLoadURL = DownLoadManager.shareInstance().getFilePathByfileID(fileID) + ".mp3"
    let infoData :NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(deliveringInfo!)  
    downloadedContentInformation.updateValue(infoData, forKey: "PodUnit")
    downloadedContents.removeAll();

    if (getDownloadInformation() != nil)
    {
        downloadedContents = getDownloadInformation()!
    }

    if(downloadedContentInformation.isEmpty != true){
        downloadedContents.append(downloadedContentInformation)
    }
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(downloadedContents, forKey: "downloadedContents")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


}
func getDownloadInformation() -> [Dictionary<String,NSData>]?{
    var returnValue : [Dictionary<String,NSData>]? =
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("downloadedContents") as? [Dictionary<String,NSData>]
    if((returnValue?.isEmpty) == true){
        returnValue = nil
    }
    return returnValue
}
```

Through two methods in PodListUnit class, I saved all that information with NSUserDefault. and then I loaded all data as below in DownLoadPlayViewController class which makes it to be shown in tableview.
Everything is fine at first. But after finishing the app, some of data (objects)in NSUserDefault will be deleted.

```
func getDownloadInformation() -> [Dictionary<String,NSData>]?
{
    var returnValue : [Dictionary<String,NSData>]? =
                 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("downloadedContents") as? [Dictionary<String,NSData>]
    if((returnValue?.isEmpty) == true){
        returnValue = nil
    }
    return returnValue
}
```

I don't understand why!!!! (I know that the data in NSUserDefulat is maintained continuously if user doesn't delete it.Can you help me to solve this problems. It is so important!!!!.

Or is they any other way to save the list of song information persistently except NSUserDefault?

Comment: Why not use Core Data or Plist?

Comment: Might be an old post, but this could work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867337/how-can-i-save-retrieve-delete-update-my-data-in-plist-file-in-ios