# Swift: How to display data from View Controller to Details View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to display particular data from a TableView to Details_View_Controller.

I have two labels. One label is a title, and I display this as a title in Details(Conference)_View_Controller.

But I have more details to display in Details_V_C. All data I retrieve from Firebase Database. In console everything is retrieved but how to display everything in Details_View_Controller?

I read this article: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH5-SW2 but I have a SWIFT 3 and this article doesn't inlcude a properly explanation to the newest version of a swift.

**JSON Tree:**

```
"conferences": {

              "date": "some date"
              "deadline": "some deadline"
              "place": "some place"
              "title": "some title"

               }
```

**View Controller(TableView):**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

        let messageSnapshot: FIRDataSnapshot! = conf[indexPath.row]
        let message = messageSnapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

       // print(message)

        let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = message["title"]

        let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        label2.text = message["place"]


        return cell!

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



        let messageSnapshot: FIRDataSnapshot! = conf[indexPath.row]
        let message = messageSnapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let confDetails = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("conferenceDetails") as! ConferenceViewController
        confDetails.title = message["title"]



        confDetails.conferenceDetailDict = message
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(confDetails, animated: true)

    }
```

**Details(Conference) View Controller:**

```
class ConferenceViewController: UIViewController {

    var conferenceDetailDict: Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(self.conferenceDetailDict)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Could someone help me to resolve this situation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you are going right way, what is the output of `print(self.conferenceDetailDict)`?

Comment: View of ConferenceViewController is not yet loaded when you set the "title" property. Create a String variable in ConferenceViewController for title, something like var titleString: String? and then on viewDidLoad() assign that title like self.title = self.titleString

Comment: @Mr.UB the output is everything from this database as you can see on JSON Tree. Everything is on the output.

Comment: @jovanjovanovic Title is set as a main title on the top of Conference View Controller. I use for this inside function for set title of ViewController. But I don't know how to set displaying rest of data in this view controller.

Answer (score 0):

One way is that if you are on TableView save into plist whatever data you want to access at Detail_V_C and get when you are loading Detail_V_C

Please see this Link:

[How can i save, retrieve, delete & update my data in Plist file in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867337/how-can-i-save-retrieve-delete-update-my-data-in-plist-file-in-ios)

```
let confDetails = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("conferenceDetails") as! ConferenceViewController
        confDetails.title = message["title"]

        //Here use the code to save into plist

        confDetails.conferenceDetailDict = message
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(confDetails, animated: true)
```

and when you load Details_V_C access plist and use data if don't need any more ,then delete all data when dismissing your confDetails_V_C.

Comment: In this solution I should create another button to save this data? Or when I click on some cell in tableView, there will be automatic saved to plistand in Detail_V_C will be displayed? When I click "back button" to a tableView this plist will delate? Because it can take some memory of this phone.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I have all values in "confDetails". I have: "confDetails.title = message["place"] and with this I have in Dedails_V_C title as a "place" value. But I would like to retrieve from this Dictionary rest of variables and past it to UILabel, to see all of this data.

Answer (score 0):

So far i understand from your question is you cannot retrieve all data from your dictionary

you can access all key and values of your dictionary by the following ways

```
var keys = [String](conferenceDetailDict.keys)
var values = [String](conferenceDetailDict.values)
```

you can iterate over your dictionary like this

```
for (keys, values) in conferenceDetailDict {
    print("\(keys): \(values)")
}
```

set your data in viewdidload