# Mock data storage and retrieval

Tags: ios, swift, data-storage, data-retrieval

I am working on building an app that stores and retrieves data on job listings. We are struggling with writing the code for storing data that is input by the user and with ways to retrieve that data on another page. Can anyone help with code that might help us do that?

Comment: you can use alamofire to network request responce. for storage you can use coredatamanager ,sqlite or lot of things you can get.create models and store the values in it. create view page and add objects of these models.please check this link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867337/how-can-i-save-retrieve-delete-update-my-data-in-plist-file-in-ios

Comment: You will need to expand more on what it is exactly you want to do. Do you want to store the user input data locally on the device or do you want it sent and stored on an external server? If its local storage on the device you can make use of `UserDefaults` or `CoreData` depending on what exactly it is you want to store.

Comment: @Hodson We are looking to create a database of job-postings. In reality we would want to use an external server, but given the limits of the hackathon we are looking to store locally. Would that utilize CoreData?

Comment: @KaitlynRabinovitz For quickness and in your situation, I would make use of a JSON file which you read and write too. You'll probably want to take a look at SwiftyJSON