# Will property list data persist after killing the application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, plist

I have created a custom property list file. The file is stored in the application document.
While user login is successful the login information is stored in the plist, and it is working fine.
The plist content are cleared while log out, this also works fine.
When i am still login i killed the application. When the app opens the plist data i cleared.

code used to save to file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xxxxPlist.plist"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
{
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xxxxPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
}
dict=[[self cleanDictionary:[dict mutableCopy]] mutableCopy];

NSDictionary *plistDict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:dict,@"login_data", nil];
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:&error];


if(plistData)
{
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
else
{
    //error here
    NSLog(@"%@ ",error);
}
```

code used to fetch data

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xxxx.plist"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
{
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xxxxPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
}

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
return [dict objectForKey:@"login_data"];
```

I there any way out to persist the data?

Comment: Your plist data is removed after relaunch?

Comment: yup when i try to fetch the data the dictionary returns nil.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867337/how-can-i-save-retrieve-delete-update-my-data-in-plist-file-in-ios

Comment: exactly i followed the same for my code.

Comment: what happened with this one

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that may be causing problems

### When saving to file

1) My understanding is that you specifically want to save to /Documents folder specifically to ensure your file persists

2) So you correctly build following path

```
"/Documents/xxxxPlist.plist"
```

3) But then why do you check if a file already exists at that location?

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
{
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xxxxPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
}
```

You just have to write to the path when you are ready.
If there is an old file at this location it will be overwritten.
And my understanding is this is the wanted behaviour, because you've already read that file and the data is in that dictionary "dict".

4) Also, by asking NSBundle to give you path for your file name

```
"xxxxPlist.plist"
```

there is a risk that it will just give you back some other path with file named the same (not in /Documents) if such file happens to exist. For example if you happened to write to say, /Cache folder earlier (with different code), your app will keep getting the /Cache path and keep reading/writong there (not in /Documents). And with the existing code you would have gotten nil here for path on the very first run, so not sure how he file got created in the first place.

5) Then I am not sure what exactly does this line

```
dict=[[self cleanDictionary:[dict mutableCopy]] mutableCopy];
```

Why first make a mutable copy, then presumably get immutable copy back and get a mutable one of it. Can't -cleanDictionary: just return the same mutable copy it was passed?

### When reading from file

1) Not sure why you're searching for a different file first?

```
"/Documents/xxxx.plist" not "/Documents/xxxxPlist.plist"
```

Also what happens if "xxxx.plist" exists, then you'll never get to "xxxxPlist.plist" that you are writing in the other section.

2) Then, yes, you have to check if a file exists at certain path before you try to read it. But, in your case, if it does not exist, you don't ask NSBundle for another location, because you need your specific file in /Documents, and you don't know what you'll get from NSBundle, if your file is not where it should be.
So if there is no "xxxxPlist.plist" file, it's just your first run of the app and you will be creating your initial dict.